# how to add a code in php echo so it will be as a popup window when called?

Tags: javascript, php, html, popup, window

I would like to insert some PHP to display the popup box. I have the following HTML/CSS/Javascript code

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <style>
        .poppup_overlay{ 
            display: none;
            position:fixed;
            top: 0%;
            left: 0%;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            background-color: black;
            background-position:fixed;
            z-index:1001;
            -moz-opacity: 0.8;
            opacity:.80;
            filter: alpha(opacity=80);
        }

        * html .poppup_overlay { /* ie6 hack */
            position: absolute;
            height: expression(document.body.scrollHeight > document.body.offsetHeight ? document.body.scrollHeight : document.body.offsetHeight + 'px');
        }

        .poppup_content {
            display: none;
            position:fixed;
            width:450;
            height:110;
            top: 40%;
            left: 35%;
            padding: 4px;
            border: 3px solid #009933;
            background-color: white;
            z-index:1002;
            overflow: auto;
        }

        * html .poppup_content { /* ie6 hack */
            position: absolute;
            margin-top: expression(0 - parseInt(this.offsetHeight / 2) + (TBWindowMargin = document.documentElement && document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop) + 'px');
        }

        .button {
            display:block;
            font-weight:normal;
            font-size:18px;
            font-family:Calibri;
            color:#009933;
            background-color:#ffffff;
            width:100px;
            text-decoration:none;
            text-align:center;
            padding:4px;
            border-top: 2px solid #b2b2b2;
            border-bottom: 2px solid #b2b2b2;
            border-left: 2px solid #b2b2b2;
            border-right: 2px solid #b2b2b2;
        }

        .button:hover,.button:active {
            background-color:#fff;
            border-color:#009933;
        }
    </style>

</head>

<body>

    <p>
        Click <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="document.getElementById('light').style.display='block';document.getElementById('fade').style.display='block'">here</a>
    </p>

    <div id="light" class="poppup_content">

        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><img src="popname.png" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr></tr>
            <tr>  
                <td><font color="#009933" face="calibri">Your message has been successfully sent !</font></td>
                <tr></tr>
            </tr>
        </table>  

        <p align="right">
            <a class="button" href = "javascript:void(0)" onclick = "document.getElementById('light').style.display='none';document.getElementById('fade').style.display='none'">Close</a>
        </p>

    </div>

    <div id="fade" class="poppup_overlay"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

You can test it online [here](http://angrybullet2.net76.net/poptest_with_css.html)

My question is how to integrate this code in php echo, so that php echoes the popup box?
If you need more details tell me. Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: popup box can provide through **javascript** not **php** you can also use **JQuery UI** dialog box for making more interactive

Comment: PHP itself is server-side programming language and it can **not** create a popup on its own. You will need client-side scripts as JS or DHTML types to do that.

Comment: @Pranav c I have created the html,javascript and css code above.
This is a look alike popup box. But how to put it in php?
@ Dainis Abols I do not want that php creates me a popup. All I need is to integrate the above code in php echo.
BOTH: Thanks for your help :)

Comment: in the same way as in html for php code u can write within `<?php //php code here ?>`

Comment: Don't support IE6, it's unnecessary. Even IE8 is on the way out

Comment: @ bfred.it Thanks for your advice. But perhaps there is some users that still use IE6. And as you know, I want my website to be available to almost everybody in the world

Answer (score 0):

`<p>Click <a href = <? echo "javascript:void(0)\" onclick = "document.getElementById('light').style.display='block';document.getElementById('fade').style.display='block'\""?>>here</a></p>`

Is this is what are you looking for?

Comment: @ Ash King no actually. I want to put the code in php echo not the php echo in the code :P. But thanks for your try :)

Comment: well its a php echo inside html but also echos out html, starting to turn into a bit of a paradox but not to worry lol